# Tracking app usage via service android studio

Tags: android, service, timer

**Goal**: To create an app that will fetch all applications on the user's phone and display them in a listview. The user may select an app on this list, and create a "time limit" for themselves on how long they get to use that app for that day via a timer. The app will run a service in the background, and check every second if the user is using said app, if so, the timer will count down, if not, the timer is "paused". Upon timer reaching 0, a pop-up will appear notifying the user that they have reached their time limit for that day. Upon closing the popup, the user will be booted out of the app.

**Issue**: I'm not sure if my method I'm using to track app usage and decrement the timer is being called every second. I tried searching on both here and on android's API, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to get my service to constantly call that method. Below is my service.

I will be happy to provide any other necessary pieces of my code that might be of assistance in solving my dilemma. Thanks in advance for any help!

**DataTrack.java**

```
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.net.TrafficStats;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;

public class DataTrack extends Service {

 int idNum = MainActivity.id;
 public CountDownTimer timer;
 int minPerHour = 60;
 int secPerMin = 60;
 int milliPerSec = 1000;
 long timeInMilliSec;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

//On creation of the service, it creates a timer using the hours and minutes the user set.
//After the initial creation, all timer functionality is handled in the "track" method below.
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    MainActivity.hasTimer = true;
    timer = new CountDownTimer((MainActivity.hours * minPerHour * secPerMin * milliPerSec) + (MainActivity.minutes * minPerHour * secPerMin * milliPerSec), 100) {
        int resetHour = R.id.editHours;
        int resetMin = R.id.editMinutes;

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeInMilliSec = millisUntilFinished;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setTitle("Times Up!")
                    .setMessage("You've run out of time, come back tomorrow!")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
            final AlertDialog timesUp = builder1.create();
            timesUp.show();
        }
    };
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    track();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}


//Tracks app usage by getting the app name and comparing it to a list of names of apps currently running.
// If the app is running, it creates a new timer. In the onTick, it stores
//the remaining time in the "timeInMilliSec" variable. If the app is not running in the foreground, or is executed
//the timer is deleted. Once the app is started up again, the timer is re-created using remaining time
//in the "timeInMilliSec" variable. This is my way of "pausing" and "resuming" the timer count down.
public void track(){
    String appName = MainActivity.applName;
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++)
    {
        if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals(appName))
        {
            timer = new CountDownTimer(timeInMilliSec, 100) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    timeInMilliSec = millisUntilFinished;
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setTitle("Times Up!")
                            .setMessage("You've run out of time, come back tomorrow!")
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                            });
                    final AlertDialog timesUp = builder1.create();
                    timesUp.show();
                }
            };
        }
        else{
            if(timer != null){
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }

        }
    }
}



@Override
public void onDestroy(){

}
```

}

Comment: Since on Android 5.0+, you have no good way of knowing what the user is doing in the foreground ("user is using said app")... why do you think that this code is going to be necessary?

Comment: @CommonsWare So the bit of code I have where I compare the app's name to the names of the currently running processes isn't going to tell me if the user is currently using the app its supposed to be tracking?

Comment: No. At most, it will tell you if a process associated with that app is running. That has little to do with whether user is *using* the app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah, okay. Since you say there is now no good way to determine what the user is doing in the foreground, is my app a lost cause? Or is there perhaps something you could point me towards that might be able to help me?

Comment: You're welcome to look at `UsageStatsManager`, though that is not real-time.

Comment: Better you can use UsageStatsManager and with the permission "PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS". 
The only thing you can use is to make a service which will get activated whenever an app is opened or in the foreground. But using a service will, of course, drain your battery. Or better to use broadcast instead.